# How to create an Ubuntu Docker image with sagemath installed on it?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, sage

I'm trying to create an Ubuntu Docker image with sagemath installed on it.

Currently, the content of my Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90never-ask
RUN apt update
RUN apt install sagemath
```

The created file manages to handle the Y/n question at the beginning of the installation.
The problem is that at the end of the installation, the installer prompts me for my location with various numbered options, and I need to answer with a number and 'enter'. (and after it I have to do it again regarding a city.)
I've tried to redirect a file with the number and new-line character to the install command like that:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY answers.txt .
RUN echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90never-ask
RUN apt update
RUN apt install sagemath < answers.txt
```

Where the content of answers.txt is:

```
8
41
```

(number and new-line at each line) but the installation hangs and I have nothing to do but terminate it.

Does anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: A ready-made Docker image of SageMath and some more math software is available at https://hub.docker.com/r/computop/sage/

Answer (score 0):

See [this other question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629046/ubuntu-14-04-dpkg-reconfigure-select-option-unattended) for a generic information on how to set options for a package to allow an unattended installation.

In your case, the package which requires configuration is actually a dependency of `sagemath`, namely `tzdata`

I succeeded using the following Dockerfile (adding a few good practice like lowering the number of unnecessary layers and reducing the layer footprint):

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN \
  echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections && \
  echo "tzdata  tzdata/Areas    select  Europe" | debconf-set-selections && \
  echo "tzdata  tzdata/Zones/Europe select  Rome" | debconf-set-selections && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get upgrade -y && \
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y sagemath && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

I've tried your Dockerfile but it fails towards the end (the error text is too long for this comment but it's basically the text of the RUN command).

Anyway, I've managed to create the image I want by installing sagemath manually and then use the Docker commit option to take a snapshot.